# mutate columns with labels attributes in r

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, attributes

I have imported data from SPSS and I want to transform some variables to factors, without having to list them all. These variables can be distinguished from the others by having the attribute labels, so I want to use the condition `length(get_labels(variable.name))>0` to mutate (or, if not possible, to select) them.

Using the following example (despite not being a `tbl_df` as would be if imported with `haven::read_sav`)

```
dt <- data.table(a = 1:4, 
                 b = factor(c(1,2,1,1), levels=1:2, labels=c("Yes","No")),
                 d = c("xxx", "yyy", "zzz", "kkk"),
                 e = factor(c(1,1,3,2), levels=1:4, labels=c("A","B","C","D")))
```

I have tried

- `dt %>% mutate_at(vars(length(get_labels(.))>0), haven::as_factor)`
- `dt %>% mutate_if((length(get_labels(.))>0), haven::as_factor)`

but that didn't work.

How can I achieve the desired result, that is, mutate/select the columns `b`and `e`?

Thanks!

Comment: So what data type are your variables then? They have labels but aren't factors. Named Vectors?

Comment: They have specific SPSS formats. Numeric variables have the format "F#" where the # represents the number of digits. So, what I call factors (in R) are F variables with labels associated with each value in SPSS. As there are other variables that have the `format.spss` F#, factors can be distinguished from these other variables by the labels associated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
library(haven)
df = read_sav("iris.sav")

is.havenlab <- function(x) "haven_labelled" %in% class(x)
df %>% mutate(across(where(is.havenlab),haven::as_factor))
```

Input (first three rows of df before mutating the is.havenlab columns)

```
# A tibble: 150 x 5
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>  <dbl+lbl>
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 1 [setosa]
 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 1 [setosa]
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 1 [setosa]
```

Output (first three rows after finding all the 'haven-labelled' columns and converting to factor

```
# A tibble: 150 x 5
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa
```

#### data.table approach

This shows an alternative function, which I've called `has.labels` (either this or the above one, `is.havenlab`) work fine.

```
df = setDT(read_sav("iris.sav"))
has.labels <- function(x) !is.null(attr(x,"labels"))
for(c in names(df)[sapply(df,has.labels)]) set(df,j=c, value = haven::as_factor(df[[c]]))
```

Comment: Thank you, @langtang, it works! Before seeing your answer I've been working around with my previous attempts and it seems to me that `mutate_if(~(length(attributes(.)$labels)>0), haven::as_factor)` works as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend selection before mutating. Something like the following to get all the columns of interest:

```r
all_cols = colnames(dt)
focus_cols = all_cols[{logic that returns T/F for each column you want}]
```

You can then iterate over all such columns as follows:

```r
for(cc in focus_cols){
  dt = mutate(dt, !!sym(cc) := as.factor(!!sym(cc)))
}
```

Where `!!sym(cc)` transforms the string stored in `cc` into a variable, and `:=` is equivalent to `=` but allows us to use `!!sym(.)` on the left side too.

Comment: @SimonSA, any suggestion on how to write the `logic that returns T/F for each column you want`? `length(get_labels(dt))>0` returns `TRUE` because at least one variable verifies the condition

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with SPSS data formats. Is the `dt` in your input example a close enough approximation? If not, you could try `true_date %>% head() %>% dput()` to produce a better example dataset.